# virtual box installation causes error while launching

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, cloudera-quickstart-vm

The virtual machine 'cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.12.0-0-virtualbox' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Sri Dhanasheelan\VirtualBox VMs\cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.12.0-0-virtualbox\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

```
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

I have installed JDK ,visual studio-2015 in my windows10 system . But still get the error that the session to open virtual machine has been failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download latest virtual box and try to re install.It will solve the problem.

Comment: yes it solved the problem for me. I tried it sequentially

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with this. In the end, the following worked for me:

> 1. Uninstall Virtual Box (fortunately, this will leave your configuration in situ).
> 2. Uninstall AVG, if you have it installed and any
>      antivirus software.
> 3. [Turn off Windows Defender](https://www.wikihow.com/Turn-Off-Windows-Defender-in-Windows-10)
> 4. Restart Windows.
> 5. Reinstall VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem occurred when running the VM with `VBoxManage`, and the fix was that I had forgotten to specify `--type headless` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with this. In the end, the following worked for me:

Uninstall Virtual Box (fortunately, this will leave your configuration in situ).
Uninstall AVG, if you have it installed and any antivirus software.
Turn off Windows Defender
Restart Windows.
Reinstall VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac, also, meet this question:

```
The virtual machine 'Linuxdemo' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Back/Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

part/unit/Component: MachineWrap

window/Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

I've just done this below to fix:

```
1. Click `apple` logo, select "`System Preferences`";

2. Chose "`Security & Privacy`", click "`General`";

3. Click your locked `lock` logo, just input your Mac password;

4. Then you will see "allow Virtual box XXX" or "allow Oracle XXX";

5. Shoot or check that mark on the right of the upstairs showing news;

6. Then, restart mac.
```

Please do the same functional operation on Windows.